# Android Google Maps - Update custom Tiles (TileProvider) without flickering (weather maps)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm using Google maps in my app with custom tiles (weather images - radar) above the maps.

Now I want to do some animation with that tiles. So the user can change the time and it will show tiles for that time. With changing time (on SeekBar) it will change the tiles and you can see the movement of the clouds/storm... (like in other weather apps).

But I have a problem with flickering the images during changing the Tiles. (I tested some other weather apps with Google maps and it should somehow work).

I tried several things:

- TileOverlayOptions.setFadeIn(false)
- TileOverlay.clearTileCache()
- Storing Tiles in memory in HashMap
- And some other options but nothing works correctly

I also find this [How to update TileOverlay without a flicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409813/how-to-update-tileoverlay-without-a-flicker) but there is not any solution. Maybe try to use more TileOverlays but I'm not sure if this will work.

Do you have some suggestions or tips on how to solve this?

Thanks for any advice.